# How does matchExpressions work in NetWorkPolicy

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I have two pods namely payroll and mysql labelled as `name=payroll` and `name=mysql`. There's another pod named internal with label `name=internal`. I am trying to allow egress traffic from internal to other two pods while allowing all ingress traffic. My `NetworkPoliy` looks like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: internal-policy
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      name: internal
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  - Egress
  ingress:
  - {}       
  egress:
  - to:
    - podSelector:
        matchExpressions:
          - {key: name, operator: In, values: [payroll, mysql]}
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3306
```

This does not match the two pods payroll and mysql. What am I doing wrong?

The following works:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: internal-policy
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      name: internal
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  - Egress
  ingress:
  - {}       
  egress:
  - to:
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          name: payroll
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          name: mysql
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3306
```

What is the best way to write a `NetWorkPolicy` and why is the first one incorrect?

I also am wondering why the `to` field is an array while the `podSelector` is also an array inside it? I mean they are the same right? Multiple `podSelector` or multiple `to` fields. Using one of them works.

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce your environment, could you confirm if you are working on pod-to-pod directly or are you exposing deployments and targetting the services for the tests?

Comment: I am working on pod-to-pod directly and exposing them as services for testing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This does not match the two pods payroll and mysql. What am I doing wrong?

- I've reproduce your scenarios with pod-to-service and pod-to-pod environments, in both cases **both yamls worked** well. That said after fixing the indentation on line 19 where both `podSelector` should be in the same level, as follows:

```
  - to:
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          name: payroll
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          name: mysql
```

---

> What is the best way to write a `NetWorkPolicy`?

- The best one depends on each scenario, it's a good practice to create one networkpolicy for each rule. I'd say the first yaml is the best one if you intend to expose ports `8080` and `3306` on BOTH pods, otherwise it would be better to create two rules, to avoid leaving unnecessary open ports.

---

> I also am wondering why the `to` field is an array while the `podSelector` is also an array inside it? I mean they are the same right? Multiple `podSelector` or multiple `to` fields. Using one of them works.

- From [NetworkPolicySpec v1 networking API Ref:](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/#networkpolicyspec-v1-networking-k8s-io)

  > `egress` [NetworkPolicyEgressRule array](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/#networkpolicyegressrule-v1-networking-k8s-io):
  >   List of egress rules to be applied to the selected pods. Outgoing traffic is allowed if there are no NetworkPolicies selecting the pod, **OR** if the traffic **matches at least one** egress rule **across all of the NetworkPolicy objects** whose podSelector matches the pod.
- Also keep in mind that this list also includes the [Ports](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/#networkpolicyport-v1-networking-k8s-io) Array as well.

---

> Why is the first one incorrect?

- Both rules are basically the same, only written in different formats. I'd say you should check if there is any other rule in effect for the same labels.
- I'd suggest you to create a test cluster and try applying the step-by-step example I'll leave below.

---

**Reproduction:**

- This example is very similar to your case. I'm using `nginx` images for it's easy testing and changed ports to `80` on `NetworkPolicy`. I'm calling your first yaml `internal-original.yaml` and the second you posted `second-internal.yaml`:

```
$ cat internal-original.yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: internal-original
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      name: internal
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  - Egress
  ingress:
  - {}
  egress:
  - to:
    - podSelector:
        matchExpressions:
          - {key: name, operator: In, values: [payroll, mysql]}
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80

$ cat second-internal.yaml 
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: internal-policy
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      name: internal
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  - Egress
  ingress:
  - {}       
  egress:
  - to:
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          name: payroll
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          name: mysql
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
```

- Now we create the pods with the labels and expose the services:

```
$ kubectl run mysql --generator=run-pod/v1 --labels="name=mysql" --image=nginx 
pod/mysql created
$ kubectl run internal --generator=run-pod/v1 --labels="name=internal" --image=nginx
pod/internal created
$ kubectl run payroll --generator=run-pod/v1 --labels="name=payroll" --image=nginx
pod/payroll created
$ kubectl run other --generator=run-pod/v1 --labels="name=other" --image=nginx
pod/other created

$ kubectl expose pod mysql --port=80
service/mysql exposed
$ kubectl expose pod payroll --port=80
service/payroll exposed
$ kubectl expose pod other --port=80
service/other exposed
```

- Now, before applying the `networkpolicy`, I'll log into the `internal` pod to download `wget`, because after that outside access will be blocked:

```
$ kubectl exec internal -it -- /bin/bash
root@internal:/# apt update
root@internal:/# apt install wget -y
root@internal:/# exit
```

- Since your rule is blocking access to DNS, I'll list the IPs and test with them:

```
$ kubectl get pods -o wide
NAME       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP
internal   1/1     Running   0          62s   10.244.0.192
mysql      1/1     Running   0          74s   10.244.0.141
other      1/1     Running   0          36s   10.244.0.216
payroll    1/1     Running   0          48s   10.244.0.17 

$ kubectl get services
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
mysql        ClusterIP   10.101.209.87   <none>        80/TCP    23s
other        ClusterIP   10.103.39.7     <none>        80/TCP    9s
payroll      ClusterIP   10.109.102.5    <none>        80/TCP    14s
```

- Now let's test the access with the first yaml:

```
$ kubectl get networkpolicy
No resources found in default namespace.

$ kubectl apply -f internal-original.yaml 
networkpolicy.networking.k8s.io/internal-original created

$ kubectl exec internal -it -- /bin/bash
root@internal:/# wget --spider --timeout=1 http://10.101.209.87
Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2020-06-08 18:17:55--  http://10.101.209.87/
Connecting to 10.101.209.87:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK

root@internal:/# wget --spider --timeout=1 http://10.109.102.5
Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2020-06-08 18:18:04--  http://10.109.102.5/
Connecting to 10.109.102.5:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK

root@internal:/# wget --spider --timeout=1 http://10.103.39.7
Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2020-06-08 18:18:08--  http://10.103.39.7/
Connecting to 10.103.39.7:80... failed: Connection timed out.
```

- Now let's test the access with the second yaml:

```
$ kubectl get networkpolicy
NAME                POD-SELECTOR    AGE
internal-original   name=internal   96s

$ kubectl delete networkpolicy internal-original
networkpolicy.networking.k8s.io "internal-original" deleted

$ kubectl apply -f second-internal.yaml 
networkpolicy.networking.k8s.io/internal-policy created

$ kubectl exec internal -it -- /bin/bash
root@internal:/# wget --spider --timeout=1 http://10.101.209.87
Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2020-06-08 17:18:24--  http://10.101.209.87/
Connecting to 10.101.209.87:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK

root@internal:/# wget --spider --timeout=1 http://10.109.102.5
Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2020-06-08 17:18:30--  http://10.109.102.5/
Connecting to 10.109.102.5:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK

root@internal:/# wget --spider --timeout=1 http://10.103.39.7
Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2020-06-08 17:18:35--  http://10.103.39.7/
Connecting to 10.103.39.7:80... failed: Connection timed out.
```

- As you can see, the connection to the services with the labels were ok and the connection to the pod that has other label has failed.

**Note:** If you wish to allow pods to resolve DNS, you can follow this guide: [Allow DNS Egress Traffic](https://github.com/ahmetb/kubernetes-network-policy-recipes/blob/master/11-deny-egress-traffic-from-an-application.md#allowing-dns-traffic)

If you have any questions, let me know in the comments.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Does it have an effect when trying to access via a service? Using the ips worked, but when trying connecting via  a service the first one doesn't work

Comment: @RiyafaAbdulHameed in my demonstration I used the services IPs as targets. In order to use DNS names you have to add an egress rule to kube-dns and you will be able to resolve the DNS name of the services, its the link I added to the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Doc link https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/policy-resources/network-policy-v1/#NetworkPolicySpec