# Create a NetworkPolicy that allows access to a pod from 2 specific pods

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-networkpolicy

Assuming I have a pod that has a label `app=foo` in a namespace.

I only want this pod to be accessible from 2 other pods in the same namespace (and no other else pod being able to access it) via a `NetworkPolicy`

These pods have the following labels

pod1

```
labels:
  app: foo1
  type: frontend
```

```
labels:
  app: foo2
  type: backend
```

My question is whether I am able to define 2 `podSelector` fields in the `ingress` section of the `NetworkPolicy` as follows

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: my-network-policy
  namespace: default
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: foo
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  ingress:
  - from:
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app: foo1
          type: frontend
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app: foo2
          type: backend
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 6379
```

Is the above `NetworkPolicy` definition going to meet my requirements?

Answer (score 0):

yes I think so, I had to mention that manifest you wrote is applied only to that pod with label foo(restriction only to foo) and ingress traffic coming either from within the cluster or outside of it  will be blocked ... however, both pods with label foo1 and foo2 can communicate or receive communication from anywhere inside your cluster . Have you implemented it ? what network plugin did you installed ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all these three pods are in the same namespace, yes, you have defined proper `NetworkPolicy`. Your yaml file is applied only to that pod with label `foo` - ingress traffic coming either from within the cluster or outside of it will be blocked but both pods with labels `foo1` `frontend` and `foo2` `backend` can communicate or receive communication from anywhere inside your cluster .

**Note:**

If you are declaring values or objects in default namespace you don't have put it in definition - like `namespace: default`. By default they will be assigned to it.

See: [matching-expression-networkpolicy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62248909/how-does-matchexpressions-work-in-networkpolicy).

Read more: [declaring-network-policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/declare-network-policy/), [network-policies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/).

Take a look: [guide-network-policies](https://www.stackrox.com/post/2019/04/setting-up-kubernetes-network-policies-a-detailed-guide/).